# Difference between SSE and Ajax Polling in browser doing queries instead of js code

Tags: javascript, ajax, ajax-polling

I've read a bit about Server Side Events and it seems to me that the biggest difference between SSE and Ajax Polling is that in latter you're supposed to query server yourself after each response, while with SSE a browser does that for you. Is it correct?

And in terms of server handling, there is almost no difference between SSE and Ajax Polling, with a minor difference of formatting the response in a certain way and including `Content-type: text/event-stream` header?

Answer (score 2):

As Seabizkit basically said, one method polls the server (as much as it wants), and the other sends messages (when the server decides to send them).

If there was a single update of some data per day, can you see what the difference would be if all clients were checking once per minute, or the server sending the message once to all who have subscribed to the event?

In your question you ask if this is correct: 'the biggest difference between SSE and Ajax Polling is that in latter you're supposed to query server yourself after each response, while with SSE a browser does that for you'. To me this means you've basically asked if the browser is doing the requests for you.

Ajax Polling is asking for data - so you can check to see if it has changed etc. (similar to a web page request) on a timed basis.

An SSE sends a message to all that want to know of the change ONLY when the change has occurred.

Polling is not querying after each response, it is querying as much as you want, when you want (10 times per second if you wish, a 100, a 1,000, whatever you deem fit).
Events occur WHEN something has happened, and subscribers are then notified (hopefully just the once).

Imagine if I wanted to know if my parcel delivery driver will be turning up within the next 30 minutes.
I could call once a minute and ask - I could do this all day long if I wanted, or the driver can just call me and let me know they are 30 minutes away.

You stated in your comment to Seabizkit that client side initiates communication. No it doesn't. It adds an event handler for an event that is available on the server. The communication after that is the server sending a message to the client, be it 5 seconds later, 5 minutes later, or 50 times per second - the client doesn't request again, it has subscribed to the event and will be notified every time it fires.

Please bear in mind that this is a general explanation - not a technical one, because your question was fairly open in asking what the difference is between the two.

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you provide detailed description of how sse works?

Comment: There are others who have already written very good examples for php and node.js (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), and MVC (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/04/10/using-html5-server-sent-events-with-json-and-aspnet-mvc/) - depends on what you need. They should get you going, hope they help.

Comment: thanks, but these are just example of the usage, they do not explain how the technology works under the hood

Comment: Hi @Maximus, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. The technology used is HTTP. The server sends data to any subscribers - the same as any other event would. You would use WebSockets when two-way communication is required, but when just sending data to a listening client, SSE is ideal - it won't get a reply from the client, it just sends to it. Barring explaining HTTP, Streams, Events, and Callbacks, I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: Hi @Maximus, saw this one today and thought it may be what you are looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870457/affects-to-the-server-from-running-eventsources

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I've read it. It's still very top level, but at least it clearly states that the client initiates the first request. This technology probably uses `HTTP persistent connection`. I'll try to figure out it on my own. Upvoted your answer as a "thanks" :)

Comment: Cheers @Maximus, I see what you mean now regarding the client initiating first. But that is only the once, opposed to constantly requesting an update...

Answer (score 0):

In the context of browsers...

The difference is: One Polls and the other responds to an Event(*).

**Polling**; is started at the browser end.

Make a request... receive response...do something. (usually change the UI)

- Polling is expensive (relative to what you are doing!).
- Polling is far easier to setup compared to handling server change on the browser.

**Server side Events/Changes**; is started at the server.

*How to notify the browser?*

- Browsers out of the box have no way to respond to service side changes.
  basically the browser has no idea that anything happened on the server.

You are left to handle this on your own.

Luckily library such as  SignalR http://signalr.net/

Can be used simplify this a lot for you. **But the complexity is still quite high compared to that of simple page with polling.**

It requires you to handle socket connections between "clients".

(*) = pinch of salt, technically not worded correctly.

*if this doesn't answer your question or you want more info ask.*

Comment: your answer is wrong, client side initiates communication

Comment: mmm.... what am i wrong about?, I'm failing to see your point. The question was "Difference between SSE and Ajax Polling in browser" what has the "client side initiates communication" got to do with anything.. no one said it doesn't nor did they say it does. Could you explain?